# Code crashing when calling function that formats an Objects properties into a String?

Tags: swift

Im trying to make a function that takes an objects properties and formats them into a String, then printing out that String as a "Description". When I run my code, I get an error "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x16)" with the return String highlighted red.

This is the function:

```
public var description: String {
        
        return String(format: "\nName: %@\nAccount Number: %@\nInterest Rate: %@\nAccount Balance: $@\nYear: %@", customerName, accountNumber, interestRate, accountBalance, year)
    }
    
}
```

Here is the call:

```
let account1 = BankAccount(accountNumber: 22, customerName: "John Smith",  interestRate: 0.3, accountBalance: 8.00, year: 2)

print(account1.description)
```

From what I've tested the object has been initialized correctly, I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: You seem to be using some objective-c syntax, to access a property or variable inside a string the swift way use `\()`, for example `"Name: \(accountName) Number: \(accountNumber)"`

Comment: Where do the arguments passed to `String(format:)` come from? What data types do they have?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1 Each placeholder has a meaning. Use the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format seems to be wrong, you have to use correct format if you want to use that method, therefore, have to use `%d` for integer, `%f` for float example:

```
String(format: "\nName: %@\nAccount Number: %d\nInterest Rate: %.1f\nAccount Balance: %.2f\nYear: %d", customerName, accountNumber, interestRate, accountBalance, year)
```

But still, recommended way for using String in swift is to use `\()`, like:

```
return "\nName: \(customerName)\nAccount Number: \(accountNumber)\nInterest Rate: \(interestRate)\nAccount Balance: \(accountBalance)\nYear: \(year)"
```